# Exit Croatia into non-Schengen state with Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, croatia

I will be travelling from Pakistan to Switzerland and then onto Croatia on a Schengen Visa. Can I exit from Croatia to Pakistan directly without reentering a Schengen state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not? Who would stop you? Just make sure to get an exit stamp when leaving Switzerland  as it will be helpful to avoid various problems should you come back to the Schengen area or need another Schengen visa later on). Do ask for it at the airport or border checkpoint if necessary. It should happen in any case but I have heard of unusual cases (crossing into Gibraltar, taking a boat…) in which people managed not to get one and had trouble coming back to a Schengen country because of that.

Comment: Thanks! I will be coming back to Switzerland so the caution note is appreciated.

Comment: Just an additional remark: You will need to ask for the exit stamp when you exit the Schengen area, which might not be when you exit Switzerland. If you are traveling over land this will be the Slovenian - Croatian border. You will not be able to get a Schengen exit stamp at a Swiss land border.